# Show date in current locale

Tags: android, date, localization, locale

I have an input date-time string:

> 2012-06-04 15:41:28

I would like to properly display it for various countries. For example, in Europe we have dd.MM.yyyy whereas US uses MM/dd/yyyy.

My current code is like this:

```
TextView timedate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.report_date);
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss"); 
curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(my_input_string); 
timedate.setText(dateObj.toLocaleString());
```

But it doesn't work exactly as I want (I always get the "uniform" result like "Jun 4, 2012 3:41:28 PM", even on my phone). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextView timedate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.report_date);
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss"); 
curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(my_input_string);

int datestyle = DateFormat.SHORT; // try also MEDIUM, and FULL
int timestyle = DateFormat.MEDIUM;
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(datestyle, timestyle, Locale.getDefault());

timedate.setText(df.format(dateObj)); // ex. Slovene: 23. okt. 2014 20:34:45
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get the current date in current locale (device locale!) :

```
String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

If you want to have the date in different styles use `getDateInstance(int style)`:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Other styles: `DateFormat.LONG`, `DateFormat.DATE_FIELD`, `DateFormat.DAY_OF_YEAR_FIELD`, etc. (use CTRL+Space to see all of them)

If you need the time too:

```
String currentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,DateFormat.LONG).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this variant:

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Got it from documentation. I mean using `format()` method.

Comment: This isn't working. Where'd you get System.err?? It's Android.

Comment: It was just a sample, where I show you using of `SimpleDateFormat` methods. You need to use `format()` method to get wishful behavior.

Comment: I know about format() function. What I don't know is how to detect current locale (e.g. US or Europe) to format it properly.